# python re.sub behaving inconsistently with re.search

Tags: python, regex

I have a section of code where I'm trying to do some search and replace. My code usually works as expected, but I'm encountering a use case that defies my expectations. In the problematic example, I have

```
input_regex = 'Cooper S \\(3doors\\)'
subst_regex = 'Cooper S Hardtop 2 Door'
```

and initially

```
input_text = 'cooper s (3doors)'
```

My code fragment:

```
matchobject = re.search(input_regex,input_text,re.IGNORECASE)
if matchobject:
    input_text=re.sub(input_regex,subst_regex,input_text,re.IGNORECASE)
```

I am expecting input_text to be changed to

```
'Cooper S Hardtop 2 Door'
```

when I'm done, but instead it's unchanged, even though I have confirmed that a Matchobject is indeed created from the `re.search`. If doing a `re.search` for `input_regex` on `input_text` was successful, why wouldn't the `re.sub` find the same match and make the replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use raw string for regex pattern. And 4th arg for `re.sub` is not flags. So make sure you specify the `flags=re.IGNORECASE` while invoking `re.sub`

```
>>> input_regex = r'Cooper S \(3doors\)'
>>> re.search(input_regex,input_text,re.IGNORECASE)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 17), match='cooper s (3doors)'>
>>> re.sub(input_regex,subst_regex,input_text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
'Cooper S Hardtop 2 Door'
```

Comment: I am able to produce that same Match object from the re.search function. My issue is that when I then proceed to run re.sub, it then doesn't find the same match in order to make the replacement.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Aha! it was the re.IGNORECASE being in the wrong position to be a positional argument. changing it to a keyword argument "flags=re.IGNORECASE" fixed my issue. Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can either go a `regex` way:

```
import re

input_text = 'cooper s (3doors)'
input_regex = '\(3doors\)'
subst_regex = 'Hardtop 2 Door'

print(re.sub(input_regex, subst_regex, input_text))
```

Or simply a non-`regex` way:

```
print(input_text.replace('(3doors)', 'Hardtop 2 Door'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
import re
input_regex = re.compile("\\(3doors\\)", re.IGNORECASE)
subset_regex = "Hardtop 2 Door"
input_text = "cooper s (3doors)"
result = input_regex.sub(subset_regex, input_text)
```

Skip the part where you do re.search. It's not needed. The result is:

```
cooper s Hardtop 2 Door
```

Note: Do not give the entire text in regex variables. It's of no use. That's not how regex works

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon a similar problem, that went away using the same compiled pattern for both matching and replacing

```
pattern = re.compile (printClose, flags)    
if pattern.search (script):
   script = pattern.sub ('', script)
```